# How to Reverse Engineer a software using Ollydbg

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse, ollydbg

I am trying to reverse a program and crack it but I cant find any of the Strings through searching for "referenced Strings" or "binary Strings".

but in view -> windows
now i see all Strings. how to use this part of ollydbg?
or its not useful for cracking

Answer (score 0):

It's because OllyDbg doesn't work as the strings utility in [linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)/[win](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings).

This question seems to be a duplicate however, with a great answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/searching-for-strings-in-ollydbg).

Btw, if you RE a binary in for instance in CTF competitions, often times a password won't hide in plain sight, you should be looking for some encryption/bit shuffling and solve that.